# Aggregation and Inheritance relationship

Tags: java

Hello everyone I have a questions about Bank.java

I have this questions :
A bank system needs to store information about bank `Accounts` and `Customers`. The bank supports two different types of accounts (Checking and Savings). All bank accounts have account `Number`, balance, and `date opened`. Two Operations are defined for all accounts, `makeDeposit()` and `makeWithdrawal()`. Checking accounts have additional attribute for check style and minimum balance. Saving accounts have additional attribute for interest rate and an operation for `calculateInterest()`.

All customers have a `name`, an `address`, and a `phone number`. In addition, a customer can have as many accounts as he needs.
The above specifications have been expanded with new requirements as follows: There are two special types of customers (`Personal` and `Commercial`). Commercial customers have additional attributes for credit rating, contact person, and contact person phone. Personal customers have attributes for `home phone` and `work phone`. Moreover, expand the model to show that the bank has multiple branches, and each account is serviced by one branch. Naturally, each branch has many accounts.
Create a simple test program (no need for using GUI or Exception Handling, just make it very simple). The name of this test program is `Bank.java`, it should make use of the above classes. `Bank.java` should declare an `ArrayList` to hold all bank accounts. The test program should utilize the system capabilities; The following are sample operations that demonstrate the systems capabilities:

a. Create a Checking account for a commercial customer in Chicago’s branch and add it to the array list
  b. Create a separate method to display the customer information and account balance. Call the method on behalf of the customer you created in the previous step.
  c. Deposit a $100 into the account you created in ‘a’, and then display the new info.
  d. Create a Savings account for an individual customer in some branch with initial balance of $100 and interest rate of 10% and add it to the array list.
  e. Display the savings account information
  f. Make a $100 deposit to the savings account, calculate the interest, then display the information
  g. Implement other operations of your choice!

This is my code I have written everything except the `Bank.java` class, I don't know from where I should start or how to do it please could anyone help me or enplane to me what should I do.

Here you can find my code :

```
 public abstract class Account{
    protected String accountNumber;
    protected double balance;
    protected String dateOpened;
    protected Customer state;
    protected Customer customer;

    public Account(){
        this.accountNumber = "";
        if (balance < 0)
            balance = 0.0;
        this.balance = 0.0;
        this.dateOpened = "";
        state = null;
        customer = null;
    }
    public Account (String accountNumber,double balance,String dateOpened, Customer state,Customer customer){
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.dateOpened = dateOpened;
        this.state = state;
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer){
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    public Customer getCustomer(){
        return customer;
    }
    public void setState(Customer state){
        this.state = state;
    }
    public Customer getState(){
        return state;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber){
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    public String getAccountNumber(){
        return accountNumber;
    }
    public void setBalance(double balance){
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
    public void setDateOpened(String dateOpened){
        this.dateOpened = dateOpened;
    }
    public String getDateOpened(){
        return dateOpened;
    }
    public void makeDeposit(double depositAmount) {
        balance = balance + depositAmount;
        }
    public void makeWithdrow(double withdrowAmount){
        balance = balance - withdrowAmount;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String output = "";
        output += "\nCustomer State: " + this.state;
        output += "\nCustomer Customer: " + this.customer;
        output += "\nAccount Number: " + this.accountNumber;
        output += "\nAccount Balance: " + this.balance;
        output += "\nAccount Date Opened: " + this.dateOpened;
        return output;
    }

}

public class Customer {
    protected String name;
    protected String address;
    protected String phone;


    public Customer(){
        this.name = "";
        this.address = "";
        this.phone = "";
    }
    public Customer(String name,String address,String phone){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String output = "";
        output += "\nCustomer Name: " + this.name;
        output += "\nCustomer Address: " + this.address;
        output += "\nCustomer Phone: " + this.phone;
        return output;
    }

}

public class CheckingAcount extends Account {
    private String checkStyle;
    private String minumumBalance;

    public CheckingAcount(){
        this.checkStyle = "";
        this.minumumBalance = "";
    }
    public CheckingAcount(String checkStyle,String minumumBalance){
        this.checkStyle = checkStyle;
        this.minumumBalance = minumumBalance;
    }
    public CheckingAcount(String checkStyle,String minumumBalance,String accountNumber,double balance,String dateOpened,Customer state,Customer customer){
        super(accountNumber,balance,dateOpened,state,customer);
        this.checkStyle = checkStyle;
        this.minumumBalance = minumumBalance;
    }
    public CheckingAcount(String accountNumber,double balance,String dateOpened,Customer state,Customer customer){
        super(accountNumber,balance,dateOpened,state,customer);
    }
    public void setCheckStyle(String checkStyle){
        this.checkStyle = checkStyle;
    }
    public String getCheckStyle(){
        return checkStyle;
    }
    public void setMinumumBalance (String minumumBalance){
        this.minumumBalance = minumumBalance ;
    }
    public String getMinumumBalance(){
        return minumumBalance ;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String output = "";
        output += "\nAccount Number: " + this.accountNumber;
        output += "\nAccount Balance: " + this.balance;
        output += "\nAccount Date Opened: " + this.dateOpened;
        output += "\nChecking Account Check Style: " + this.checkStyle;
        output += "\nChecking Account Minumum Balance: " + this.minumumBalance;
        return output;
    }
}

public class SavingAccount extends Account {

    private double intrestRate;

    public SavingAccount(){
        this.intrestRate = 0.0;
    }
    public SavingAccount(double intrestRate){
        if (intrestRate < 0)
            intrestRate = 0.0;
        this.intrestRate = intrestRate;
    }
    public SavingAccount(double intrestRate, String accountNumber,double balance,String dateOpened,Customer state,Customer customer){
        super(accountNumber,balance,dateOpened,state,customer);
        if (intrestRate < 0)
            intrestRate = 0.0;
        this.intrestRate = intrestRate;
    }
    public SavingAccount(String accountNumber,double balance,String dateOpened,Customer state,Customer customer){
        super(accountNumber,balance,dateOpened,state,customer);
    }
    public void setIntrestRate(double intrestRate){
        this.intrestRate = intrestRate;
    }
    public double getIntrestRate(){
        return intrestRate;
    }

    public double calculateInterest() {
        return intrestRate;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String output = "";
        output += "\nAccount Number: " + this.accountNumber;
        output += "\nAccount Balance: " + this.balance;
        output += "\nAccount Date Opened: " + this.dateOpened;
        output += "\nSavingAccount Intrest Rate: " + this.intrestRate;
        return output;
    }
}

public class Personal extends Customer {
    private String  homePhone;
    private String  workPhone;

    public Personal(){
        this.homePhone = "";
        this.workPhone = "";

    }
    public Personal(String homePhone,String workPhone){
        this.homePhone = homePhone;
        this.workPhone = workPhone;
    }
    public Personal(String homePhone,String workPhone,String name,String address,String phone){
        super(name,address,phone);
        this.homePhone = homePhone;
        this.workPhone = workPhone;
    }
    public Personal(String name,String address,String phone){
        super(name,address,phone);
    }
    public void setHomePhone(String homephone){
        this.homePhone = homephone;
    }
    public String getHomePhone(){
        return homePhone;
    }
    public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone){
        this.workPhone = workPhone;
    }
    public String getWorkPhone(){
        return workPhone;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String output = "";
        output += "\nCustomer Name: " + this.name;
        output += "\nCustomer Address: " + this.address;
        output += "\nCustomer Phone: " + this.phone;
        output += "\nPersonal Home Phone: " + this.homePhone;
        output += "\nPersonal Work Phone: " + this.workPhone;
        return output;
    }
}

public class Commercial extends Customer {
    private double cridetRating;
    private String contactPerson;
    private String contactPersonPhone;

    public Commercial(){
        this.cridetRating = 0.0;
        this.contactPerson = "";
        this.contactPersonPhone = "";
    }
    public Commercial(double cridetRating,String contactPerson,String contactPersonPhone){
        this.cridetRating = cridetRating;
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
        this.contactPersonPhone = contactPersonPhone;
    }
    public Commercial (double cridetRating,String contactPerson,String contactPersonPhone,String name,String address, String phone){
        super(name,address,phone);
        this.cridetRating = cridetRating;
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
        this.contactPersonPhone = contactPersonPhone;
    }
    public Commercial (String name, String address, String phone){
        super (name,address,phone);
    }

    public void setCridetRating(double cridetRating){
        this.cridetRating = cridetRating;
    }
    public double getCridetRating(){
        return cridetRating;
    }
    public void setContactPerson(String contactPerson){
        this.contactPerson = contactPerson;
    }
    public String getContactPerson(){
        return contactPerson;
    }
    public void setContactPersonPhone(String contactPersonPhone){
        this.contactPersonPhone = contactPersonPhone;
    }
    public String getContactPersonPhone(){
        return contactPersonPhone;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String output = "";
        output += "\nCustomer Name: " + this.name;
        output += "\nCustomer Address: " + this.address;
        output += "\nCustomer Phone: " + this.phone;
        output += "\nCommercial Cridet Rating: " + this.cridetRating;
        output += "\nCommercial Contact Person: " + this.contactPerson;
        output += "\nCommercial Contact Person Phone: " + this.contactPersonPhone;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many people will not follow a link, for various reasons. By not including your code your are reducing the chance of finding an answer to your question. You may also receive down votes as well.

Comment: Why can't you try coding whatever you want to accomplish and ask questions if you are stuck

Comment: I did put my code.

Comment: What i did in the bank class         import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Bank {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Account> arrAccountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
  CheckingAcount myAccount = new CheckingAcount(" CheckStyle "," 100 ");
  arrAccountList.add(myAccount);
  
 }

}

Comment: But he want to create a chickening Account with commercial Person how i can do that. How i can connect both class

Comment: My questions is if i did the Array fof Account i should have an other Array for the commercial Person. But he's questions is like this: Create a Checking account for a commercial customer in Chicago’s branch and add it to the array list b. Create a separate method to display the customer information and account balance. Call the method on behalf of the customer you created in the previous step.

Comment: Why did you omit all linebreaks and produced an unreadable "wall of text" while copying your homework here?

Comment: Well if you are gonna copy/paste your homework, at least make it readable!

Comment: I don't know how you can say it's not readable!!!

Comment: I think it's clear your the only one said that it's not readable ><

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are going in the correct direction with your class objects.  You still have little more to go before we can jump in when you think you are super stuck.

hint:  Commerical vs Non-Commerical try a true/false property on the Account class object, should eliminate need for multiple lists, but it does increase complexity slightly. Placing it here creates the relationship you are looking for I believe.